# Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot boots straight to windows

Tags: dual-boot

Windows/Ubuntu dualboot started booting directly to windows after enabling virtualization in bios and installing virtual box for minikube installation on Ubuntu. Prior to this change, dualboot had been running successfully and booting to grub, from which I could pick Ubuntu or windows.

Multiple attempts to run boot-repair and running bcdedit to set bootmgr to point to grubx.efi still continues to boot to windows rather than grub.

Laptop is hp envy dv7. Bios boot order only lists "os boot manager" and does not have an option to pick Ubuntu.

See output of boot repair at https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YSy78frkhR

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Enabling virtualization and/or installing Virtualbox does NOT change the boot order. Some Windows feature updates or automatic Firmware (UEFI) updates may do that. Please pay attention to *Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS entry (sda2/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware* message in the report. Have you checked UEFI > Boot?

Comment: Yes I agree it shouldn't change boot order and since only a single os boot manager option appears in my bios, I don't know what it could change anyway. My bios has no other options to pick Ubuntu, which is why I was relying on bcdedit to set grubx.efi as the bootmgr. Running bcdedit shows that its pointed to that file but still boots straight to windows.